# how does addition of 8-bit or 16-bit offsets in jump instructions take place?

Tags: assembly, x86, offset

I have doubt whether in IA-32 architecture in case of jumps that use 8-bit or 16-bit offsets, addition of that offset to EIP register can affect the bits of EIP that don't have matching bits in offset as well or it is like addition of just part of the EIP register that matches the offset in number of bits to the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about an operation like `add eip,xxx` then it's a 32-bit add, and you don't need to worry about the fact that one operand starts out narrower.

Update - missed the fact that this was actually about relative JMP instructions.   The answer to that is that no, you don't need to worry about the size of the relative jump offset operand, the jump will work properly.

Here's the current Intel documentation:

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Comment: I'm talking about JMP instruction not ADD.

Comment: so you mean jumping by a 16-bit offset like 0x8888 and adding it to EIP register will be exactly like jumping by a 32-bit 0x00008888 offset and adding it to EIP?

Comment: Well, 0x8888 is a negative number, so it would be like doing a 32-bit relative jump of 0xffff8888, but I don't think that was the point you trying to make.   A relative jump of 0x44 is the same as one of 0x0044 and one of 0x00000044.  There are lots of other issues as you get into big jumps and protected-mode operation, but I suspect you don't need to worry about them here.

Comment: yeah I didn't mean anything into signed logic but you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

Short Jumps are only addition between EIP and 8bit or 16bit (or 32ibt) signed immediate value. If new EIP will not start at the right code address than an exception will raise.

**From Intel: INSTRUCTION SET REFERENCE***

> Near and Short Jumps. When executing a
>   near jump, the processor jumps to the
>   address (within the current code
>   segment) that is specified with the
>   target operand. The target operand
>   specifies either an absolute offset
>   (that is an offset from the base of
>   the code segment) or a relative offset
>   (a signed displacement relative to the
>   current value of the instruction
>   pointer in the EIP register). A near
>   jump to a relative offset of 8-bits
>   (rel8) is referred to as a short jump.
>   The CS register is not changed on near
>   and short jumps. An absolute offset is
>   specified indirectly in a
>   general-purpose register or a memory
>   location (r/m16 or r/m32). The
>   operand-size attribute determines the
>   size of the target operand (16 or 32
>   bits). Absolute offsets are loaded
>   directly into the EIP register. If the
>   operand-size attribute is 16, the
>   upper two bytes of the EIP register
>   are cleared, resulting in a maximum
>   instruction pointer size of 16 bits. A
>   relative offset (rel8, rel16, or
>   rel32) is generally specified as a
>   label in assembly code, but at the
>   machine code level, it is encoded as a
>   signed 8-, 16-, or 32-bit immediate
>   value. This value is added to the
>   value in the EIP register. (Here, the
>   EIP register contains the address of
>   the instruction following the JMP
>   instruction). When using relative
>   offsets, the opcode (for short vs.
>   near jumps) and the operand-size
>   attribute (for near relative jumps)
>   determines the size of the target
>   operand (8, 16, or 32 bits).